# Failing test class

Tags: class, testing, salesforce, apex-code

I'm working on the solution posted here: http://mysalesforcecode.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-copy-record-owner-from-cloning.html

The button and trigger work just as hoped, but I keep getting a test failure due to the second system assert in my test (testing if the opportunity owner was retained per the original owner field. I'm an apex novice, so I could be doing something obviously wrong... hope so - Thanks!

Button:

```
{!URLFOR( $Action.Opportunity.Clone,Opportunity.Id,     
[cloneli=1,opp11='Prospecting',opp12='10',opp9= 
TEXT(MONTH(Opportunity.CloseDate))+"/" 
+TEXT(DAY(Opportunity.CloseDate))+"/" 
+TEXT(YEAR(Opportunity.CloseDate)+1) 
])}&00NZ0000000kfYf={!Opportunity.OwnerId}&retURL={!Opportunity.Id}
```

Trigger (updated per answer below):

```
trigger OwnerIdChange on Opportunity (before insert)
{
 for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
 {
  if(o.OriginalOwner__c != null)
     o.OwnerId = o.OriginalOwner__c;
 }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
private class Opportunities_Test {

    static testMethod void Opportunities_Test1() {
    test.starttest();

      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
      User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com',
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');
      insert u;

      Profile s = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
      User u2 = new User(Alias = 'admin', Email='admin@testorg.com',
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing2', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = s.Id,
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='admin@testorg.com');
      insert u2;

     Account a = new account(Name = 'Test1');
     insert a;

     List <Opportunity> Opportunity;
            Opportunity O1 = new Opportunity();
            O1.ownerid = u.id;
            O1.accountid = a.id;
            O1.Amount= 1;
            O1.CloseDate = Date.today();
            O1.Name = 'Testing';
            O1.StageName= 'Prospecting';
            insert O1;

 Account b = new account(Name = 'Test2');
 insert b;

      List <Opportunity> Opportunity2;
        Opportunity O2 = new Opportunity();
        O2.accountid = b.id;
        O2.ownerid = u.id;
        O2.Amount= 1;
        O2.CloseDate = Date.today();
        O2.Name = 'Testing2';
        O2.StageName= 'Prospecting';
        O2.OriginalOwner__c= u2.id;
        insert O2;  


List<Opportunity> z = [SELECT Id, Ownerid, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE id= :O2.id];

 system.assertEquals(O1.ownerid, u.id);
 system.assertEquals(O2.OwnerID, u2.id);

     test.stoptest();          
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code to the current. An interesting note is that while the test class fails due to the second system assert at the end, the trigger says it has 100% coverage. Of course, I could make the test class pass by removing the assert, but I really want to do this right.

Comment: As of today, still no final solution... please see my last comment on Mar 6 at 18:13 (below) - The process works fine in the sandbox (keeps the original opportunity owner when I create using the button)... I just can't get the test class to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger logic is a bit crazy, try changing it to the following and see if you get different results.

```
trigger OwnerIdChange on Opportunity (before insert)
{
   for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new)
   {
      if(o.OriginalOwner__c != null)
         o.OwnerId = o.OriginalOwner__c;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Per the comments below it should also be pointed out that he is not getting the updated value of the record after he inserts and updates them. Re-query the opportunity records and assert based off those returned values.

Comment: The trigger in the blog is confusing. The use of Trigger.new.clone() makes no sense.
The trigger posted by jonnybro does the same thing and it works for bulk updates (not sure how to do bulk cloning). The important thing is to have the OriginalOwner__c set by the button before the clone is executed.

Comment: @jonnybro Thanks for your response. I updated the trigger and still get the same error when running the apex test at the second system assert:                                                    Error Message System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 005Z0000000tb5YIAQ, Actual: 005Z0000000tb5ZIAQ

Comment: @user2120892 You need to re-query the owner value for the second opportunity after it is inserted. Only then will you have the value set by the trigger.

Comment: @jonnybro Above, I edited the last last part of my Test class - Maybe I'm not understanding, but the system.assertequals is after the insert... and now after an added update. I've moved around the stop test and I still can't get it to pass - As stated before, the process works fine, even after updating the trigger. Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: @user2120892 Even after an update you still need to query the record again to get the new values of the fields. If you change your second assert to read system.assertEquals(u2.Id, z.OwnerId); You will be good to go...

Comment: @jonnybro I made this change and get the error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<Opportunity> at line 52 column 33 (*this location is where z.OwnerId starts). Since the criteria in the query would call both opportunities (both had the stagename of prospecting), I tried to altered the where Name = Testing3 and it still did not work. Thanks for sticking in there with me and the time you have spent thus far.